# What is the synth effect of the voice in 'Funkytown' by Lipps Inc?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, voice

I always listened to this song and the FX that the voice as in the verse always fascinated me. Now that I'm into producing and sound design I'm wondering how to obtain it.

Comment: It's a vocoder, from memory.

Comment: A vocoder is used in the female and male vocal tracks.

Comment: Thanks! But I notice some "airy" sound in the voice fx. Do you know how to set the vocoder to obtain it?